# How to download all of project euler's problems using wget

Tags: ftp, wget, mirroring

I'm trying to download all of [Project Euler's](http://www.projecteuler.net/) problems using the command `wget -m http://www.projecteuler.net/` but all it downloads is the first page 
i.e `index.html` and stops. I've tried using `--user` and `--password` but it gives me the same results. They also don't seem to have an ftp site which is possibly why it didn't work. **Is there some other way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)?

Try this commandline:

```
curl http://projecteuler.net/problem=[1-442] -o "problem#1.html"
```

Obviously you have to look up the current number of problems once before the download.

The benefit compared to wget -m is that it only downloads the relevant files and does not mirror the complete site.

Comment: haha,I love it. I didn't know `curl` was this good. Is there a way to do the same in `wget`?

Comment: As far as I know wget can't do it that simple. I guess with wget you need a script which calls wget in a for-loop with the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> wget -m  **http://projecteuler.net/**

it will fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks, it works. Those guys should fix this, it's breaks the POLS.